# convert sql query to Activerecord query rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this sql query:

```
      sub = "(select Name from other_holders s where s.share_holder_id=share_holders.id and s.other_holder_type_id=1) as secondHolderName"   
      sub1 = "(select Name from other_holders s where s.share_holder_id=share_holders.id and s.other_holder_type_id=2) as thirdHolderName"       
      @shareHolders=ShareHolder.select("Folio_no,Name,#{sub},#{sub1}")
```

I am getting the required result from this query,But i am not satisfied with this.I want to convert this whole query to Activerecord query.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ShareHolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :second_holders, class_name: OtherHolder, ->{where( older_holder_type_id: 1)}
  has_many :third_holders, class_name: OtherHolder, ->{where(other_holder_type: 2)}
end
```